# get a number of elements in 2d array, in shape of (*array)[column]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I declared a 2d array in main function and I want to get the number of elements in another function.

Let's say my main is like this.

```
#define col 100
#define row 10

int main(){
   array[row][col] = {"abc1", "abc2", "abc3"};
   int len = get2DLen(array);
}
```

and I copied this array in this form (*array)[column]

```
int get2DLen(char (*array)[col]){
   int len;
   //some operations..
   return len;
}
```

Questions are..

> how can I get col in func? In this case, 10.

> how can I get the number of actual elements in the array? In this case, 3.

I'm aware of the fact that array means *array[0] in here.

I tried to iterate all the elements and check if it's '\0' like a normal char array string. But it's just absolutely wrong.. cause it was initialized anyway..

so any help would be appreciated

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're asking about their differences.

Comment: okay.. sorry for that. I'll edit it

Comment: C does not do this for you automatically. To do it, do it manually: Pass the array dimensions as arguments to the routine: `int get2DLen(size_t row, size_t col, char (*array)[col])`. (`size_t` is declared in `<stddef.h>`.)

Answer (score 0):

In C, it's not possible to determine the size of the array. Therefore, you can't get `col` in the function. You need to pass the dimension of the array to the function parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define col 100
#define row 10

int get2DLen(char (*array)[], size_t arr_row, size_t arr_col)
{
    int len = arr_col;
    return len;
}

int main()
{
    char array[row][col] = {"abc1", "abc2", "abc3"};
    int len = get2DLen(array, 3, 4);
    printf("%d", len);
}
```

Comment: I made a tree consist of nodes that include 2d array. For tree related functions, I can't pass every node's array size. That's why I needed to calculate the size in the function. But It turns out there's no operation like that. Maybe I should add size of array in the node.. Anyway thanks for your input.